# Avoid duplication when using other table in WHERE and JOIN clause in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, join, greatest-n-per-group

I have 3 tables (`devices`, `shops`, `device_shops_versions`). `devices` can have many `device_shops_versions`.

`device_shops_versions table`:

```
+----+---------+-----------+---------+---------------------------+
| id | version | device_id | shop_id | updated_at                |
+----+---------+-----------+---------+---------------------------+
| 1  | 113     | 1         | 1       | 2014-05-05 17:03:25.04055 |
| 2  | 702     | 1         | 1       | 2015-05-05 17:03:25.04055 |
| 3  | 410     | 2         | 1       | 2014-05-30 09:29:44.88214 |
| 4  | 440     | 4         | 2       | 2013-06-30 08:28:42.98214 |
+----+---------+-----------+---------+---------------------------+
```

1) I want to return all the devices using `device_id` that are in `device_shops_versions` for a specific `shop_id`.

2) I want to display the most recent `version` of every device in `device_shops_versions` - with the most recent `updated_at`.

I should have something like:

```
+----+--------------+---------+-----------+---------+--------------------------+
| id | device_model | version | device_id | shop_id | updated_at               |
+----+--------------+---------+-----------+---------+--------------------------+
| 1  | 'iphone'     | 702     | 1         | 1       | 2015-05-05 17:03:25.040  |
| 2  | 'test'       | 410     | 2         | 1       | 2014-05-30 09:28:44.982  |
+----+--------------+---------+-----------+---------+--------------------------+
```

My query looks like this but I'm not sure I'm correct and also I would like to know if I can avoid the duplication :

```
SELECT *
FROM devices
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT device_shops_versions.device_id,
          MAX(device_shops_versions.updated_at)
   FROM device_shops_versions
   GROUP BY device_id ) dcv ON devices.id = dcv.device_id
WHERE devices.id IN
    (SELECT device_shops_versions.device_id
     FROM device_shops_versions
     WHERE device_shops_versions.shop_id = 1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT ON`, it's considerably shorter, simpler and probably also faster:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (device_id) *
FROM   devices_shop_versions
WHERE  shop_id = 1
ORDER  BY device_id, updated_at DESC NULLS LAST;
```

Detailed explanation:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

If your table is big, you have *many* rows per `device_id` and you need to optimize performance, a recursive CTE might be faster, yet. Detailed instructions:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)

Make it a subquery to integrate in a bigger query:

```
SELECT mv.id, d.device_name, u.user_name, mv.version, mv.device_id, mv.shop_id, mv.updated_at
FROM  (
   -- query from above
   ) mv
JOIN   devices d on d.id = mv.device_id
JOIN   users   u on u.id = d.user_id
-- ORDER BY ???;  -- optional
```

[Demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/PNZBAM9638)

It's typically cheaper to join to more tables *after* excluding irrelevant rows.

Comment: Also how does it fit into a full query like : http://rextester.com/XLMS29779

Comment: @Mio: Yes, the link was wrong. I added an integrated query and a new link for that.

Answer (score 2):

```
with maxVer as
(
    select id, version, device_id, shop_id, updated_at,
           row_number() over (partition by device_id order by version desc) rn
    from devices_shop_versions
    where shop_id = 1
)
select id, version, device_id, shop_id, updated_at
from   maxVer
where  rn = 1;
```

Add a row number partitioned by device and ordered be version on descending order.

```
row_number() over (partition by device_id order by version desc)
```

Then get the rows where rn = 1 (Max version)

This is the result:

```
+----+---------+-----------+---------+---------------------+
| id | version | device_id | shop_id | updated_at          |
+----+---------+-----------+---------+---------------------+
| 2  | 702     | 1         | 1       | 05.05.2015 00:00:00 |
+----+---------+-----------+---------+---------------------+
| 3  | 410     | 2         | 1       | 30.05.2014 00:00:00 |
+----+---------+-----------+---------+---------------------+
```

Check it here: http://rextester.com/SXUMZ94595